# Spring returns EmptyCollectionEmbeddedWrapper instead of just an empty array

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

(Using only @RepositoryRestResource and methods defined inside the repository)When making an http request and a repository method returns no result, is there any workaround to change the returned "content" to an empty array if it really is empty , instead of :
HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Writing [Resources { content: [org.springframework.hateoas.core.**EmbeddedWrappers$EmptyCollectionEmbeddedWrapp**

My repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "some", path = "some")
public interface SomeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SomePojo, String>
{}
```

false:

```
 "content": [
    {
      "value": [],
      "rel": null,
      "collectionValue": true,
      "relTargetType": "xy.cxyPojo"
    }
  ]
}
```

good:

```
   "content": []
}
```

Edit: **found the solution, it is the following:**

The best and easiest solution i found finally for this so far is the following. Implement a custom ResourceProcessor, which is automatically picked up and used by spring(because of the @Component). Override the process method and in the method return a new Resource() which is initialized with an empty list, instead of the old Resource you got as an argument, add the links and all what you want and that's it. Like this:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;
import org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceProcessor;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Resources;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

@Component
public class ResourceProcessorEmpty implements ResourceProcessor<Resources<Object>>
{
    @Override
    public Resources<Object> process(final Resources<Object> resourceToThrowAway)
    {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

// In my case i needed the request link with parameters, and the empty content[] array

        Link link = new Link(request.getRequestURL().toString() + "?" + request.getQueryString());
        Resources<Object> newResource = new Resources<>(Collections.emptyList());
        newResource.add(link);
        return newResource;
    }
}
```

For clarification: if you use `Resources<Object>`, that will handle empty collections(when that "EmptyCollectionEmbeddedWrapper" dummy object would be returned), whereas `Resources<Resource<Object>>` will handle non-empty collections. In this case the first needs to be used.

Comment: Please add the code you are using.

Comment: I added my repository, but i think it doesnt have much to do with my code, it is by default doing this. By default if there is no result to show instead of returning an empty array, it makes EmptyCollectionEmbeddedWrapper from my pojo and returns that as the one object in the array.

Comment: You don't have a controller? Are you utilizing Spring Data REST?

Comment: Yes, no controller just @RepositoryRestResource and methods defined in there like:findByStartTimestampBetweenOrEndTimestamp..

Comment: edited post with the class and method responsible for this behaviour.